# Is there way to convert Friday, August 31, 2018 12:12 PM into this format 2018-08-31 12:12 PM in sql?

Tags: sql, date, date-conversion

I am trying to find a difference between two dates both in different formats. Is there way to convert `Friday, August 31, 2018 12:12 PM` into this format `2018-08-31 12:12` PM in sql? and how can I then find the difference?
the results should be in `hh:mm:ss` format, using metabase to run queries.

Comment: Which _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: @prithu sharma please tag database you are using. It will help to answer the exact query.

Comment: Note that for finding the difference, you really don't want the PM notation — you want 24-hour clock notation.  If your input data has no information about seconds, the output difference will always have 00 for the seconds notation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using Metabase to run the query. Unsure of the version

Comment: @Tajinder query looks like this SELECT DISTINCT taa.ticketid,
       convert(varchar(19),getdate(), 120) as ticket_creation_date,
       taa.value AS assigned_agent,
       (CASE WHEN ta.performer_type = 'system' AND taa.value IS NULL THEN 'system-unassigned' WHEN ta.performer_type = 'system' THEN 'system-assigned' WHEN taa.value = ta.performer_id THEN 'self-assigned' WHEN taa.value IS NULL AND ta.performer_type = 'user' THEN 'user-unassigned' ELSE 'other-assigned' END) AS assignment_type,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help